# Custom Drag & Drop not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to drag a div and drop anywhere in its parent div . For dragging I use css style

```
draggable="true"
```

and for drop, I use 'mousemove' event X and Y values and use this values for div top and left .The code I used is

```js
$(".drop").mousedown(function () {
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
       var k = e.clientX ;
        var  f = e.clientY;
    
         $(".drop").text(k+ ", " + f);
         $(".drop").css("top",f);
          $(".drop").css("left",k);
    }); 
 }).mouseup(function () {

    $(this).unbind('mousemove');
    
      
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

```css
.drop{
   position:  absolute;
    left: 300;
    top: 200; /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
    width: 200px; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
    border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.gridPart{
 padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gridpart">
  
     <div class="drop" draggable="true" ></div>
  <div>
```

Now it's drag & drop if I drag with increasing left value. But if I drag with decreasing left value it's not dropping. And how I stop the drag if it reach the end of the main div(GridPart)?

Comment: is there a reason you dont want to use a library for this? drag & drop can be notoriously difficult to get working cross browser and platform, so perhaps something like http://draggabilly.desandro.com/ or since you're using jquery already, https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: i don,t want code using library .  can you help me with this code?

Comment: do you want to limit dragging to just the x axis? (discerned from your mention of `end of the main div`) are you trying to make a slider? or do you need `drop` detection?

Comment: no i drop my div only inside the grid part div

Comment: @manupadmanabhan You can look at my answer below where I fixed your issue and explained.

Comment: tanks@aruna its working perfect. i have can't up vote u because i have less point. tanks a lot ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. All you did is quite good but you should have to use the `mousemove` event with `$(document)` element and not with the div. Since when you drag backwards, mouse movement is going out of the div and so its no longer dragging.

Also, as you used custom dragging, you don't need to use `draggable="true"`.

```js
$(".drop").mousedown(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
       var k = e.clientX;
        var  f = e.clientY;
    
         $(".drop").text(k+ ", " + f);
         $(".drop").css("top", f + 'px');
          $(".drop").css("left", k + 'px');
    }); 
 });

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');        
});
```

```css
.drop{
   position:  absolute;
    left: 300;
    top: 200; /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
    width: 200px; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
    border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.gridPart{
 padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gridpart">
  
     <div class="drop" ></div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the JQueryUi Draggable:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

UPDATE: sample code here:

http://embed.plnkr.co/5W3ACU/

Comment: OP mentioned in the comments they do not wish to use a library for drag/drop

Comment: Sometimes we need to think about reinventing the wheels

Comment: I completely agree! just per OP's request :(

Answer (score 0):

I think what i have discerned from your question you are trying to do, is limit dragging to within the `.gridpart` div.

The key was moving the drag detection to the container div, and then moving the drag component based on the mousedown position

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1oLyjbqu/5/)**

**JS**

```
$(".gridpart").mousedown(function () {
    var containerDims = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var dropEl = $(this).find('.drop');
    // measure the size of the drop element
    var dropDims = dropEl[0].getBoundingClientRect()
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        // position the element centered under the cursor
        var k = e.clientX - dropDims.width / 2;
        var f = e.clientY - dropDims.height / 2;
        if( k >= 0 && k <= containerDims.width - dropDims.width){
             dropEl.css("left",k);
        }
        if(f >= 0 && f <= containerDims.height - dropDims.height){
            dropEl.css("top", f);
        }
        dropEl.text(k + ', ' + f);
    });
 }).mouseup(function () {
    $(this).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.drop{
    position:  absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    width: 200px; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
    border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
    z-index: 3;
    /* prevent 'shadow' drag preventing mouseup firing */
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -khtml-user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-drag: none;
    -o-user-drag: none;
    user-drag: none;
}
.gridpart{ /* correct camelcase typo */
    background-color: #F00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    height: 58px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridpart">  
    <div class="drop" draggable="true">0, 0</div>
<div>
```